# How would I solve this inequaility?

Tags: inequality

I need to show, using differentiation, that: $$1-x^2\le e^{-x^2} \quad \text{for $0\le x\le1$}$$

However I don't know why differentiation helps . Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to apply calculus to maximize the function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}-1+x^2$?

Comment: Well, the inequality is clear if $|x|\geq 1$. So it remains to show for the case $|x|<1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I don't think it has a miximum

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Yes, that is true! I will edit know

Comment: Oops, sorry, I wrote the wrong thing. Try to *minimize* the function. Which is just what the answer of @mrnovice does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x)= e^{-x^{2}}+x^{2} -1$

$f(0) = 0$

$f'(x) = -2xe^{-x^{2}}+2x = 2x(1-e^{-x^{2}})$

Setting $f'(x) = 0:$

$2x(1-e^{-x^{2}})=0$

$\Rightarrow x=0 $ or  $e^{-x^{2}}= 1 \Rightarrow x =0$

For $x> 0$ we can clearly see that $f'(x)>0$

$\Rightarrow f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function $\forall x\geq 0$

Therefore $f(x) \geq f(0) = 0$ as required

Comment: Not that it took long, but why bother finding critical values? I think it's clear from your expression for $f'$ that $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x \geq 0,$ which is all you wanted.

Comment: Yes it's true, that part is redundant, mainly included due to force of habit, and that it was pretty simple.